# Refactoring tool in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-plugin

My need is pretty simple: I want to change a method call `objClass1.method1()` by a call `objClass2.method2()` in my whole Eclipse project. Unfortunately, I can't find a plugin able to do this. Can you help?

**Edit:**

To be more accurate, `objClass1` is part of a third party library, so I need to change the method calls. I can't start at the method definition. When I right-click on a method1 call, I have no "rename" option in my "Refactor" menu.

I don't want to change or rename my methods. I want to exchange one call by another in my whole project.

An example of what needs to be done:

Before refactoring:

```
Injector injector=Guice.createInjector(new IContactModule());
```

After refactoring:

```
Injector injector=IContactInjectorSingleton.getInjector();
```

And this needs to be done a several points in my project.

Comment: Does this works: Right on method name. Goto Refactor-->Rename.

Comment: To do a sound refactoring, you'd need to always have `objClass2` available where `method1` is called. Is this requirement fulfilled in your project?

Comment: For this to work there must be many more modifications be done ... right? If 'objClass1' isn't of the same type as 'objectClass2' the constructor calls have to be edited, too! I don't see how this can be automated. If I don't understand what you want an example of "Code before refactoring"=>"Code after refactoring" might make the question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click on the class/method name and choose Refactor > Rename.

EDIT:

> To be more accurate, objClass1 is part of a third party library, so I need to change the method calls. I can't start at the method definition. When I right-click on a method1 call, I have no "rename" option in my "Refactor" menu.

Hence I would suggest you to simply make a replacement:

**Search menu > File, type the old name, choose the context of the search ("Enclosing project"), click on Replace and type the new name.**

EDIT2:

From the example you added to the question I think that a manual replacement, using the tool I just suggested, it's the best way. It's a complex issue, as @Arne pointed out, so it's better to make it in a controlled way. Moreover I doubt it is such a frequent operation to require a plugin to be built.

Comment: Seems very insecure to me. That's a simple string replacement. I can't really see it as refactoring...

Comment: I gave it a try. It broke all the concerned classes, since the import for Class2 is missing...

Comment: @Traroth so you need also to remove all imports of Class1 and add all imports for Class2.. please specify all this in your question. Now I'll upvote it, it's a good question. Just clarify it, for future readers.

Comment: So it seems a specific tool for doing just that doesn't exist. That's a shame, since it is a very obvious need...

Answer (score 6):

What you ask for is no refactoring. A refactoring is defined as "a change that alters the code while not changing the behavior of the code". In this sense renaming a class or renaming a method is a refactoring (you change the code but the program does the same as before). But what you suggest does NOT preserve the behavior of the code so there will never be a "refactoring" for this.

Of course one might be able to write a plugin that is able to perform the text changes you want in a more or less safe way. But this will only work in very specific circumstances (what if your new method needs an argument the old one dons't need? What if there are more than one method with the same name but different parameters? ...). So I don't believe such a plugin exists, nor it makes much sense to develop such a plugin.

Comment: Agreed concerning the terminology point. But it's a bit more than simply "text changes", as I looked for something searching references of a method to change them. And solutions for the parameters can be imagined making such a tool very useful, actually. For example, the tool suggesting the attributes and local variables visibles in the scope of the code calling the method you try to change...

Comment: But if the tool asks me for every line of code what to do (which local variables to use ...) then the difference to use "Find Reference" and fixing the code by hand is quite small. I'm pretty sure such a plugin does not exist.

Comment: I disagree. Being sure not missing any reference of a method would be an interesting feature in itself, but with some work, it surely could be made very easy and quick to change the code, much quicker than doing it by hand, and maybe at least partially automated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the eclipse refactoring by selecting the methods name. Right click for context menu or Alt-Shift-R, in the Rename-Dialog a preview dialog is available which shows all suggested changes in one place.

Answer (score 1):

First, move the body of `objClass1.method1()` into `objClass2.method2()`, and have `method1` simply call `method2`.  It may not be quite as "simple" as that, if for instance `method1` uses fields of `Class1` for instance, in which case you should probably include `this` as a parameter to the new method and perhaps use getters for the fields. If you can make the method static before doing this, it will be easier to avoid those kinds of problems. Anyway, make that transformation, so `method1` is just calling `method2`.  Now use the Inline Method refactoring to make `method1` go away. You're done.

Comment: excellent way of doing this! does not help in this case as it is a 3rd party lib, but in other cases helps a ton!